# composer: How to find the exact version of a package?

Tags: php, dependency-management, package-managers, composer-php

Suppose I'm writing a library A, that depends on another library, monolog for instance.

I want to install the latest version of monolog, so I just put this inside composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "*.*.*"
    }
}
```

Then I run `$ php composer.phar install`.

I was expecting to find the version installed, inside composer.lock, but it's not there:

```
{
    "hash": "d7bcc4fe544b4ef7561918a8fc6ce009",
    "packages": [
        {
            "package": "monolog/monolog",
            "version": "dev-master",
            "source-reference": "2eb0c0978d290a1c45346a1955188929cb4e5db7"
        }
    ],
    "packages-dev": null,
    "aliases": [

    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "stability-flags": [

    ]
}
```

I need the version because I want to tie my library to a specific set of versions, eg: If I find the version is 1.3.5, in my composer.json I would like to put something like this:

```
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "1.3.*"
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: A somewhat related tip for this question: if you are using PhpStorm as your IDE, any `composer.json` files will show you next to each dependency the actual version you have installed.

Answer (score 238):

I know it's an old question, but...

```
composer.phar show
```

Will show all the currently installed packages and their version information.  (This was shown in previous versions of Composer only when using the now-deprecated `-i` option.)

To see more details, specify the name of the package as well:

```
composer.phar show monolog/monolog
```

That will show many things, including commit MD5 hash, source URL, license type, etc.

Comment: `php composer.phar show -a` and `php composer.phar show package/name` are also both helpful.

Comment: For `dev-master` packages, this is useful, because it also shows the commit hash. So you need to go to GitHub, find that commit hash, check the date, and then find the tag with the nearest date before that, to really find out what "version" you are using

Comment: it can also be find in composer.lock file.

Comment: To list all packages starting with a certain string, you can use the `*` wildcard:
`composer show 'package/*'`

Answer (score 81):

You can use composer show like this:

```
composer show package/name
```

Answer (score 21):

If you're just interested to get the output as the package version number like: **1.7.5** or **1.x-dev** or **dev-master**.

Linux console snippet (composer & sed):

```
composer show 'monolog/monolog' | sed -n '/versions/s/^[^0-9]\+\([^,]\+\).*$/\1/p'
```

or (composer, grep & cut):

```
composer show 'monolog/monolog' | grep 'versions' | grep -o -E '\*\ .+' | cut -d' ' -f2 | cut -d',' -f1;
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks. I used this to compare Symfony version between multiple projects.

Answer (score 11):

You can use show all, specially when dont have package.json file, get available packages from packagist.org:

```
composer show "monolog/monolog" --all
```

Also you can specify versions

```
composer show "monolog/monolog" 1.* --all
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [git version control system](https://git-scm.com/), you will search easily for any package

```bash
composer show |grep packagename
```

For Example

```bash
composer show |grep monolog
```

If you aren't installing git, you can install grep program from [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/), link it with environment variables and write same previous command in **`Cmd`**

If you don't know how to link program with environment variables, [view this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3036325/5661396) after linking it write the same command on the above

Answer (score 6):

Technically "dev-master" is the exact version that you ended up using there. It is the development branch, and thus the very latest version.

The best place to look for available versions for composer packages is [Packagist](http://packagist.org) since that's the place composer loads the versions from when you install packages. The monolog versions are listed on http://packagist.org/packages/monolog/monolog.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check the version within PHP itself, you can use the composer Runtime Utilities:

```
\Composer\InstalledVersions::getVersion('my/package')
```

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/07-runtime.md for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To find a package by name run this command ( laravel is an example)

```
composer search laravel
```

To find info about a package  run this command ( laravel/laravel is an example)

```
composer show -a laravel/laravel
```