# Broken text in Qt Creator UI

Tags: user-interface, text, windows-7, qt-creator, text-rendering

Sometimes (not always), certain text items in the Qt Creator UI are broken:

[image: Broken text in Qt Creator UI]

**Any idea what causes it? Or a workaround?**

Maybe the problem is my cheap video card (an Intel on-board one). This theory is supported by the fact that Creator is probably QML-powered by now, meaning it's running on OpenGL.

I tried restarting Creator and that fixed it, but after switching between the Welcome and Edit tabs a few times, it happens again.

I tried making Creator's UI use the software QML renderer, rather than OpenGL, as that might have made it work correctly. I did it by running the following in `cmd.exe`:

```
> set QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
> qtcreator.exe
```

But that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution is the same as that to [the problem I posted next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081028/qml-garbled-text-with-colorful-pixels-around-it-on-intel-gpu), i.e. to make the app (Qt Creator in this case) use ANGLE. Except I don't want to recompile Qt Creator just to add one line of code, so I use the alternative approach in [the Qt doc page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers), which is to set the env var `QT_OPENGL` to `angle`, before launching Creator.

At least so far it hasn't bugged out on me.

Note: The setting of an env var can be done conveniently with a batch file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036367/122687).