# QML: Garbled text with colorful pixels around it on Intel GPU

Tags: qt, windows-7, intel, visual-artifacts, qt5.7

Screenshot of one of the Qt Creator example apps:

[image: Garbled text screenshot]

My videocard is a *Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family*.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [solution](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers) was to call either:

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);
```

or

```
QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseSoftwareOpenGL);
```

before instantiating `QGuiApplication`. I don't know exactly why it worked :)