# Setting env var on launching shortcut doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, environment-variables, shortcut

I'm looking at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3036367/122687) and trying to apply it in my scenario.

My batch file is as follows:

```
@echo off
REM // https://stackoverflow.com/a/39084914/122687
set QT_OPENGL=angle
start "D:\ProgramFilesOnD_NoSpaces\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe"
```

And I've created a shortcut (pinned to the Windows 7 start menu) that points to this batch file.

When I click the shortcut, the following happens:

- а command prompt window appears for an instant, then it disappears
- another command prompt windows appears. It doesn't disappear, and it looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

- Nothing else happens.

**Any idea what's going wrong?**

Comment: Put `""` in between `start` and the remaining command line, as `start` may interpret the first quoted string as a window title...

Comment: @aschipfl: Not a duplicate. I'm not trying to pass any parameters to Qt Creator.

Comment: Don't focus on the arguments, look at the quotation issue described in the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/154090)...

Comment: @aschipfl: The answer there does solve my problem, but the *question* is not a duplicate ;) Anyway, thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Comment: @aschipfl: Ah, now I read that under SO's definition of a duplicate, my question is indeed a duplicate. I marked it as such, thanks.